# Improve sparql query to extract all the words of different categories from a Dbnary (dbpedia)

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbnary

I am trying to retrieve from Dbnary database based on dbpedia  all words belongigs to categorie of noun, adjectif, adverb and verb and their synonyms.

So far I get can access it just for one categorie but I would like to know how to improve my query to get all words from the 4 categories and their synonym with  only one query rather than making one query per category (i.e 4 query and 4 files)

```
#Query for noun which work 

SELECT DISTINCT * where {
?l a ontolex:LexicalEntry;
lime:language "fr";
ontolex:canonicalForm ?f ;
lexinfo:partOfSpeech lexinfo:noun ;
ontolex:sense ?s .


?f ontolex:writtenRep ?w .
OPTIONAL { ?l dbnary:synonym ?syn ; rdfs:label ?synonyme .}
}

LIMIT 100
```

This query work , you can test it since dbnary in online :  http://kaiko.getalp.org/sparql

but I wanted to upgrade the query below. When adding the following line on the previous query, it does not work :

```
#lexinfo:partOfSpeech lexinfo:verb ;
```

Any help will be fine.

Comment: just adding the triple indeed doesn't work because logically this is the intersection or "and". What you want is a union or "or" - there are multiple ways to achieve this, e.g. by means of a filter: `FILTER (?pos in (lexinfo:noun, lexinfo:verb))` and write `lexinfo:partOfSpeech ?pos; ` - or you can provide those POS tags as inline data via `VALUES ?pos {lexinfo:noun  lexinfo:verb}` - or you use a good old `UNION`, i.e. `{?l lexinfo:partOfSpeech lexinfo:noun } UNION {?l lexinfo:partOfSpeech lexinfo:verb }`

Comment: Thank you, but I do not understand How to insert those lines ? Should I pout them after the optional parameter